# Calendar.MONTH returns wrong value

Tags: android, calendar

I want to get current month from Calendar.

I used two ways:
First:

```
int gcmonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Second:

```
Calendar c = (Calendar)Calendar.getInstance();
int gcmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Both ways returns 2 (March), but I want to get 8 (September - current month).

EDIT: The date on my phone is right! September 12, 2013 23:32 (Kyiv time)

Comment: What is the date setted in your phone device?

Answer (score 2):

### Both of your method totally depends on Device Date

Check your Phone date it will receive date from your device and will give the output

```
Calendar c = (Calendar)Calendar.getInstance();
int gcmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

### this returns 8

this also returns 8

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

There is no issue with your code only it is due to Device date

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM", Locale.getDefault());
String currentDate = sdfDate.format(new Date());
```

This is it. It will return 09. September.

Comment: Why should `Locale` work if Calendar doesn't work? According to Android's docs, getInstance() "Constructs a new instance of the Calendar subclass appropriate for the default Locale and default TimeZone, set to the current date and time." So what does `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SEPTEMBER)` return? If it returns 8, then your phone just doesn't have the date correct.